# How to divide an Fragment in Android into Two Colors

Tags: android, android-studio

First I would like to say please do not mark this question a duplicate. It differs from other posts in one critical way. Does anybody know a way that I may divide the color of fragment into two colors right down the middle? Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Shark I don't think Spannables can be used split the rendering of a single letter. You can change things for each letter, but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: @DougStevenson fair enough, I didn't really clearly understand what the OP asked. I still don't... Oh, i think I get it now. Example: he wants a red-black 'A' letter to be red color on the left half, and black color on the right half.

Comment: Are we sure that's what the OP asked?  "divide the color of the text view" says to me that its the textview background he wants divided in two, not the letter rendering.  He MAY mean that, but its not clear.  OP?

Comment: you can use gradient.

Comment: Yes the text color is to stay the same, it is the background of the textview that I would like to change the color of

Comment: could you post a image what exactly you want to achieve ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I achieved this by creating the ideal background in photoshop, saving it as a `.png`, and then setting that as the activity background for when I need it to be. Simple, clean, easy, and because I only need it to be two colors all the time, I don't have to worry about the image becoming pixelated.

Answer (score 5):

here is sample to use gradient

```
  float in[] = new float[] {0f,1f};
    TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
    Shader shader = new LinearGradient(
            0, textView.getTextSize(), textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight(), new int[]{Color.RED, Color.BLUE},in,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    textView.getPaint().setShader(shader);
```

To achieve Second Simply user Framelayout xml

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_test"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_test2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

For Third one you have to write little and do some work on pixel level

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="H"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textSize="100sp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_test"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_test2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_test"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
View linearLayout;
View tvTest2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
    Shader shader = new LinearGradient(
            0, textView.getTextSize()/2, textView.getTextSize(), textView.getTextSize()/2,Color.RED, Color.BLUE,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    textView.getPaint().setShader(shader);

     linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.ll_test);
     tvTest2 =  findViewById(R.id.tv_test2);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_test);

            Bitmap b1 = getBitmapFromView(linearLayout);
            Bitmap b2 = getBitmapFromView(tvTest2);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(textEffect(b1, b2));
        }
    },2000);

}

public Bitmap textEffect(Bitmap image, Bitmap text) {
    if (image.getWidth() != text.getWidth() ||
            image.getHeight() != text.getHeight()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimensions are not the same!");
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x) {
            int textPixel = text.getPixel(x, y);
            int imagePixl = image.getPixel(x,y);

            int red = Color.red(textPixel);
            int blue = Color.blue(textPixel);
            int green = Color.green(textPixel);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(textPixel);

            Log.i("TAG", "textEffect: "+x+"-"+y+",-->"+red+","+blue+","+green+","+alpha);

            /*Since text color is white so give the color of background to it 
            * else make it white*/
            if (red == 255) {
                if (blue == 255) {
                    if (green == 255) {
                        image.setPixel(x, y, imagePixl);
                    }else
                    {
                        image.setPixel(x, y, textPixel);
                    }
                }else{
                    image.setPixel(x, y, textPixel);
                }
            }else
            {
                image.setPixel(x, y, textPixel);
            }
        }
    }
    return image;
}


public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
}
```

What you exactly want to achieve ??
First one 
Second one 
Third one ?? 
[image]

Comment: If you could tell me which one you exactly want ? I will post the code accordingly.

Comment: The second one what I am trying to achieve, except the entire fragment will be divided into two colors.

Comment: Right, so how could I implement this into a button onClickListener? so that when I click a button once it splits the screen and when I click it again it goes back to the normal white background?

Comment: second one is super easy simply take click event and only change background color of view as per click event.

Comment: Got it, ad I will be integrating a remote control into this application, as I've never ever integrated an RF remote into an android application, do you know of any tutorials for assigning the received signals to activities?

Comment: Sorry I have another question. I am trying to implement the second option you created above. But am still confused how this will work. And instead of a fragment, I've defined it as a relative layout. But the principle should still be the same. Can you post a code of how to divide a relative layout in two onClick? I can't seem to wrap my mind around this one

Answer (score 2):

Define a TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="O"
    android:textColor="#88022b54"
    android:textSize="250sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:shadowColor="#ff2e7cca"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="1"/>
```

Then

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(
            0, mytv.getTextSize()/2, mytv.getTextSize(), mytv.getTextSize()/2,
            Color.RED, Color.BLUE,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    mytv.getPaint().setShader(shader);
```

Comment: As far as I know, no problem. Have you seen running? It's almost what you wanted, yes?

Comment: No I haven't can you send me a link? Also can you edit the code to fragment_standard? It needs to be split vertically so that red is on the left half and blue is on the right half

Comment: @user154248 please check the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>Erste Farbe</font> <font color=#ffcc00>zweite Farbe</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```